# Google Compute Engine write/read metadata

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, service-accounts

I encountered a problem when trying to add metadata to a Compute Engine Instance from itself (from inside the instance).

In the IAM I created a specific service account with Compute Instance Admin (v1) role `test-compute@test.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

When instantiating the VM I specify the previous service account : `test-compute@test.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

When I connect with ssh to the VM, I can see that the account is set to the right service account.

```
gcloud config list
[core]
account = test-compute@test.iam.gserviceaccount.com
disable_usage_reporting = True
project = test-project

Your active configuration is: [default]
```

> Then when I try to add metadata to my VM (from the VM itself) I get this error.

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata --metadata "start=true" --zone europe-
west1-b <INSTANCE_NAME>
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.add-metadata) Could not fetch resource:
 - The user does not have access to service account 'test-compute@test.iam.gserviceaccount.com'.  U
ser: 'test-compute@test.iam.gserviceaccount.com'.  Ask a project owner to grant you the iam.service
AccountUser role on the service account
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible problems that cause this error:

1. Your VM instance does not have the required scopes.
2. Your Service Account does not have the required IAM roles.

The default Service Account for Compute Engine only has the Editor role. However, this is often changed so I am specifying a two step process to solve this problem.

You will need to shutdown the instance to change settings for your instance.

- Go to Compute Engine -> VM instances.
- Shutdown your instance.
- Click on your instance.
- Click on the "EDIT" button at the top.
- Scroll down to the bottom and click "Set access for each API".
- Scroll down to "Compute Engine"
- Change the permission to "Read Write".
- Click Save and start your instance.

Note that VM instance "Cloud API access scopes" cannot provide permissions to the VM instance that your Service Account does not have. If you still have the same error message, then you will need to add the role `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` to your Service Account.

- Go to IAM & admin -> IAM
- Locate your Service Account. Located at the right hand side is a pencil icon. Click it.
- Click ADD ANOTHER ROLE
- Scroll down to Service Accounts. Select Service Account User.
- Click SAVE.
- Go back to Go to Compute Engine -> VM instances and start your instance.

Answer (score 0):

When I add `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` to my Service Account, it works. Since the user is the service account (User == ServiceAccount) I don't get why I have to add this role ?

Comment: The role is needed to set instance metadata https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#iam.serviceAccountUser